# How sign a message on Near with Meteor Wallet in js app?

Tags: meteor, nearprotocol

I would like to get the signature of a message 'hello' on Near in my Next Js app.

I wanted to use this code : https://docs.near.org/develop/integrate/backend-login, but I did not manage to connect to Meteor wallet and get the signature.

Do you know how to handle it ? Do you have any code to share ?

I implemented to logic on https://docs.near.org/develop/integrate/backend-login, but I don't understand how to connect to Meteor.

What I want is that the user sign a message in a wallet, and then I get the signature of the message 'hello'.

Answer (score 1):

the docs here: https://docs.near.org/develop/integrate/backend-login assume that you have already setup the wallet selector.

To communicate with Meteor Wallet you need to use Wallet Selector on the frontend and add setupMeteorWallet to modules: https://github.com/near/wallet-selector#installation-and-usage

After you setup the wallet selector you can communicate with Meteor Wallet like this:

`const meteor = await selector.wallet("meteor-wallet");`

`const signedMessage = await meteor.signMessage(params);`

Comment: i still don't see the signMessage function with typescript